# Using Async_reader and Wave Parser in DirectShow filter graph results in video seeking issues

Tags: c++, video, directshow

Some background:

I am attempting to create a DirectShow source filter based on the pushsource example from the DirectShow SDK. This essentially outputs a set of bitmaps, each of which can last for a long time (for example 30 seconds), to a video. I have set up a filter graph which uses Async_reader with a Wave Parser for audio and my new filter to push the video (the filter is a CSourceStream and I populate my frames in the FillBuffer function). These are both connected to a WMASFWriter to output a WMV.

The problem:

When I attempt to seek through the resulting video, I have to wait until a bitmap's start time occurs before it is displayed. For example, if I'm currently seeing bitmap 4 and skip back to the time which bitmap 2 is displayed the video output will not change until the third bitmap starts. Initially I wondered if I wasn't allowing FillBuffer to be called enough (as at the moment it's only once per bitmap) however I have since noted that when the audio track is very short (just a second long perhaps), I can seek through the video as expected. Is there a another way I should be introducing audio into the filter graph? Do I need to perform some kind of indexing when the WMV has been rendered? I'm at a bit of a loss...

Comment: That is, you obtain a well-built WMV file (in terms of playback without seeking), and then playing it *with* seeking introduces the issues?

Comment: Yes, the WMV plays fine but as soon as I attempt to seek is when I hit problems. As soon as the time of the next frame after where I seek to occurs then playback of the video resumes normally (the audio always seeks correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do indexing as a post-processing step. Try indexing it with Windows Media File Editor from [Windows Media Encoder SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23848) and see if this improves seeking.

Reducing key frame interval in the encoder profile may improve seeking. This can be done in Windows Media Profile Editor from the SDK. Note that this will cause file size increase.

Comment: I've tried indexing and this doesn't seem to make any difference. I've examined the file with ASF viewer against a working WMV (which I've output using the same code, with a generated frame sequence which runs at 50fps). I've also tried outputting more samples (ie. the same frame repeatedly) but this also doesn't work unless the frames are changing.

Comment: Did you try changing keyframe interval?

Comment: I've just tried this (by setting the WM_SampleExtensionGUID_OutputCleanPoint property to true at a defined interval) and it's solved the problem. Thanks!